# How to queue data from an ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Currently I get 50 rows of data from mysql database using php on the back end and use jquery and ajax to request the data on the front end. How can I get the next 50 rows of data in advance while viewing the current 50 rows of data on the front end using jquery and ajax?

Comment: You perform another ajax query?

Comment: Select rows with offset and limit and serialize your data structure into JSON and send that JSON to client and process it.

Comment: I guess I can get 100 rows instead of 50 rows and display 50 rows at a time. Any other ideas are welcome. Thanks

Comment: may be send `id` to the server and process the next 50 to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a paging problem with an eager load of the next page.  I would add a method called GetNextPage that gets the next page and holds it in memory.  The next page UI on the actual page just pulls the next page from memory and then calls GetNextPage from the server loading it in to memory.  When the page loads initially, call this method to queue up the next page... it may never be used.  Of course that is a simple view.  You need to handle the case when a user clicks the button a bunch of times... perhaps disable it.

You could also have the next page load into a div that is hidden.  The advantage here would be that if you have images they will load... so when the user clicks "Next Page" they have the illusion that it loaded really fast when in fact it is loading the page after that in a hidden div and just showing the previously loaded page.

- I should clarify that when I say memory, I mean client side... make the calls as ajax calls and store them client side.  It should all be async and the server should not know of state.

Comment: what if i click three, four times.

Comment: if the button is disabled... you cant.  You could write a queue.  Perhaps a pubsub approach would work best for that.  Just be sure you can handle the responses out of order.

Comment: I updated my resp... When I say get it and put it in memory I mean make a second ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

After grabbing the first 50 rows and displaying the data, you can continue making calls using Ajax, just store the results in an array until needed. Probably a php `$_SESSION` array would be easiest place to store it for later use.